# EncryptByPassPhrase returns special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, character-encoding

I'm trying to encrypt with `EncryptByPassPhrase` in SQL Server 2012 but when I execute this function I get values like `"öK{8+¨´¡¿" ...` maybe someone can help me?.

This is the code that i'm using:

```
IF(@MODE = 1)
BEGIN
    SET @RESUL = convert(varchar(100),ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('Prueba','200000'))<br>
    PRINT 'ENCRYPT'+ (CAST(@RESUL AS varchar(20)))
END
```

Comment: Yes, that is expected. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: I have to insert this password encrypted in a table.. but when i want to read it don't give me anything (I thought that ecncryptbypassphrase give me the result with an "enter") ...so I took the print result and tryed to decrypt with DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE but the function return me "NULL".

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down. According to the documentation, the output of `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE()` is varbinary. You're `CONVERT`ing that to varchar. According to the documenation for convert, if you don't provide a style, convert "Translates ASCII characters to binary bytes or binary bytes to ASCII characters. Each character or byte is converted 1:1.". If you're looking for something more like `0x123abc`, pass an additional parameter (1) to `CONVERT` to make it do that.

All that said, unless you need a human to be able to transcribe the encrypted content (or otherwise interpret it), I'd leave it in its varbinary representation. Less room for error on the decryption side. Specifically:

```
DECLARE @resul VARBINARY(8000);
SET @RESUL = ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('Prueba','200000');
SELECT CAST(DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('Prueba', @resul) AS VARCHAR(50));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ben.
I've tried to convert the result to VARBINARY but is not working. 
I can't use DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE to decrypt this special characters.. I thought that the format resulting will be something like 0x11sf... but is not

Comment: I've added the code above to do the encryption and decryption without first having to go through a textual representation. You should treat the varbinary as opaque. For the same reason you don't open a JPEG file and say "I can't see the picture". :)